# 3D effect with shadow effects on CSS3

Tags: html, css

am trying to realize this 3D effect using css3, [image]

This is what i've try so far :

```
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px #000000;
```

Comment: Why don't you just look at the source...? Link the website and we shall give you the exact effect

Comment: Could you post the link? I'm kind of curious on how they did it :p

Answer (score 4):

To make a shadow like above image you have to use after before CSS3 tag and apply to div.

```
.effect
{
     position:relative;       
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

.effect:before, .effect:after
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    top:10px;
    bottom:10px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
} 
.effect:after
{
    right:10px; 
    left:auto;
    -webkit-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
    -moz-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
    -ms-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);     
    -o-transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg); 
    transform:skew(8deg) rotate(3deg);
}
```

visit to [stupidcodes.com](http://stupidcodes.com) for more example...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is more than I asked...:)

Answer (score 0):

```
.shadow-bottom {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```